# Using jQuery Mobile with cordova-qt

Tags: javascript, jquery, qt, cordova

I managed to use jQuery mobile with phonegap and the app is working on iPhone and blackberry.
But when i try to use jquery mobile with phonegap for Qt (cordova-qt + Qt Creator) jquery didn't work. is it possible to do that?

I added the following lines to the index.html file found in the www folder of the cordova qt library:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" type="text/css"/> 
<script language="javascript type="text/javascript" charset="utf=8" src="jquery.js"> </script> 
<script language="javascript type="text/javascript" charset="utf=8" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
```

Then I added this jQuery files beside `index.html`, anything missing?

Answer (score 0):

What isn't working? Trying cordova-qt too at the moment and using jQueryMobile is working pretty well.